# How to compare two csv files line by line in apachi nifi flow file using groovy script

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I have once scenario in apachi nifi, that is i have a csv data in the flow file and i have the some csv data in my database which has some different data than the csv flow file, now i want to compare both csv files(flow file content from my nifi flow file and ,csv data which i read from database) using groovy script, could you please help me how can i achieve this using nifi. I have my data like below.

```
existing content(123_456.csv) from db
    

A   3000    AAA008
A   3001    AAA008
A   3002    AAA008
A   3003    AAA008
A   3005    AAA008
A   3006    AAA008
A   3007    AAA008
A   3008    AAA008
A   3009    AAA008
A   3010    AAA008
A   3011    AAA008
A   3012    AAA008(This record is deleted in the new file from the flow file, so i dont need to consider this from the new file)



 Flow file content(123_456.csv) from apachi nifi flow file
    
A   3000    AAA008
A   3001    AAA008
U   3002    AAA009(This I need to update, since the third Colum is changed)
A   3003    AAA008
I   3013    AAA113(This I need to insert ,since I don't have this in the old file from the db)
A   3005    AAA008
A   3006    AAA008
A   3007    AAA008
A   3008    AAA008
A   3009    AAA008
A   3010    AAA008
A   3011    AAA008
```

Could you please help me with the groovy script, to achieve this. Thank you

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Hi @cfrick, unfortunately i have no idea how to do this in groovy, i have done the same in java, but i needed to do this in the groovy , could you please guide me

Comment: Read http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html and use your java code; should only take minor adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 lists A & B
Create 2 Sets A-match & A-nonmatch
Create 2 Sets B-match & B-nonmatch

Then loop through A matching up to B - Add matches to A-match Add non-matches to A-nonmatch
Then loop through B matching up to A - Add matches to B-match Add non-matches to B-nonmatch

Now you have a sets of
matches from A to B
nonmatches from A to B
matches from B to A
nonmatches from B to A